# Upload new version of file using Alfresco API

Tags: alfresco

i'm trying to upload a new version for document using java and Alfresco Rest APIs 
I didn't find a method that satisfy what i need to do 
Can you please help ?

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you targetting? Some of the nicer new Rest APIs aren't available in old versions of Alfresco, so it matters!

Comment: I'm using version 5.2

Comment: What's wrong with [put /nodes/{nodeId}/content endpoint](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/updateNodeContent)?

Comment: That method changes the content of an existing document. But i'm trying to upload new one

Comment: You asked for a new version, that's different! For a whole new document, not a new version to an existing one, you want the entry a few lines above - [post /nodes/{nodeId}/children](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode)

Comment: You can find rest api here. https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes

Answer (score 0):

When using the Alfresco 5.2 REST API...

Create a new node:
https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode

Update a node with a new version:
https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/updateNodeContent

Alternatively, because you are using Java, you might consider using the Apache OpenCMIS Java Client to work with nodes so you can avoid having to deal with REST calls. [Here](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/create-objects/index.html) are some examples.